# Mean squared velocity of a particle moving in a logarithmic potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, potential

> A particle of mass $m$ moves in the logarithmic potential 
>   $V(r)= C\ln(ar)$.     $C$ and $a$ are constants.
>   What is the mean squared velocity of the particle?

Do I have to solve this in conventional way? I don't know how to start. First Solving SE with this given potential seems to me a tough task. Is there any other way this could be answered easily?

Comment: Please use a question mark (?) at the end of any English sentence which is a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consider the viral theorem then you can relate the expectation value of the kinetic energy to the potential. Just make sure to use a fully general form, like one that involves the derivative of the potential.

After you have the kinetic energy you should be able to get what you want easily.